# How to select all files in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have files whose extension is `.AH`. For example:

```
aa.AH
bb.AH
cc.AH
dx.AH
tmz.AH
lght.AH
```

I want to select all of these files, but not one by one because I use `saclst` (it's a command to read and write seismogram headers), and it needs all files for comparison for NPTS (which is the number of points).
So I use this code:

```
for file in *AH
   do

   nptsAH=$(saclst npts f ${file}* > nptsAH.txt | awk '{print $2}' nptsAH.txt | sort -n | head -1)
   declare -i nptsAH

   sac << !
   r $file
   interpolate NPTS $nptsAH
   w over
   q
   !
   done
```

Which form is correct for bash scripting?

Comment: In a for loop, you loop over the files one by one. How would you want to pick the files, but not one by one if you want to loop over them?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the files. You may want to add your usage scenario.

Comment: @pLumo I edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable cannot hold multiple files or a pattern. But you may use an array:

```
files=(*.AH)
```

or

```
files=()
for file in *.AH; do
   files+=("$file")
   ...
   some_command using "$file"
done
...
some_command using "${files[@]}"
```

[See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49844/how-to-put-the-specific-files-from-a-directory-in-an-array-in-bash).

Comment: second one is working, thanks @pLumo

Comment: ITYM you can use an array variable instead of a scalar variable. In Korn-like shells, `var=value` is a scalar variable assignment. It can only store one value. In zsh/ksh93-like shells, `var=(...)` is either a compound, array or associate array variable assignment depending on the shell and whether a type was given to the variable with `typeset` beforehand. In any case those are all *variables* (though with different types).